# Mac OS Resize Button

Tags: macos, swift3

How to trigger a event when resize button is [resize button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNMZJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

**windowDidResize function**

From the developer [website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419567-windowdidresize), you can find this function declaration from `NSWindowDelegate`:

```
optional func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification)
```

> Tells the delegate that the window has been resized.

So, for illustration sake (in **Swift 4**):

```
class YourViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    // constructors and other methods are omitted for illustration simplicity

    func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
        // You can listen to window resize event here
    }
}
```

**Other useful functions**

Note that there is other **sizing windows functions** available:

```
func windowWillResize(NSWindow, to: NSSize) -> NSSize
```

> Tells the delegate that the window is being resized (whether by the
>   user or through one of the setFrame... methods other than 
>   setFrame(_:display:) ).

```
func windowWillStartLiveResize(Notification)
```

> Tells the delegate that the window is about to be live resized.

```
func windowDidEndLiveResize(Notification)
```

> Tells the delegate that a live resize operation on the window has
>   ended.